# 401 error while fetching guild details Discord

Tags: node.js, discord

I'm trying to access a discord server details using discord api but it shows `401 authorized error`. I'm using an access token and the user is the member of the server I'm fetching details of.
Moreover,
The authorize url is
`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize` with scope `email guilds guilds.members.read connections identify`

Answer (score 0):

It seems, we can fetch guild details with `Bot` as a token and also when it's actually invited in the guild.